# Plug-in reloader

Tags: pyqgis

There's something I don't understand in the behaviour of the "**Plugin Reloader**" plugin: When an error occur in the test of a plugin "**Plugin Reloader**" reloads a new instance of my plugin (the one with corrections made) but the former instance of that plugin (the "bugged" one) remain visible, making the two instances hard to distinguish (...)

Would it be a way to automatically remove the former instance ?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? This issue doesn't seem to exist in QGIS 2.8.

Comment: I'm using QGIS 2.12 and the latest version of plugin reloader (0.6.3) ...

Comment: Did you try with another plugin than yours as well?

Comment: Well ... the problem appear when there's an error in the code ... i mean i my code ... how could i test it with another plugin ?